# CU updates with SP2?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am planning to update My MOSS SP1 to SP2. But SP2 was released almost 2 years back. After that there were so many CUs released. If download SP2 for MOSS. Will all CUs will come with SP2 or Do I need install CU separately after installing SP2.

Please give me suggestions

Comment: Here is the main page
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb735839
and here the details
http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/cc263467%28en-us,office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install SP2 and then your required CU:

From the [April 2011 CU](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2512782)

> Prerequisites
>
> To install this hotfix, you must have 2007 Microsoft Office Servers Service Pack 2 installed

Don't forget to upgrade WSS and MOSS!